# how to get average value of a partition data with sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
type        id             qty          hour       date
a           manual          1             2     2020-05-06
a           manual          2             3     2020-05-06
a           manual          4             6     2020–05-06
b           manual          2             4     2020-05-03
b           manual          1             2     2020-05-03
b           manual          4             5     2020-05-03
```

I need to get the productivity by dividing qty and hour, my query is:

```
select type, date, qty/hour as prod,
from table1
where id = ‘manual’
group by type, date
```

with the query above, I got:

```
type        id             qty          hour       date            prod
a           manual          1             2     2020-05-06         0.5
a           manual          2             3     2020-05-06         0.67
a           manual          4             6     2020–05-06         0.67
b           manual          2             4     2020-05-03         0.5
b           manual          1             2     2020-05-03         0.5
b           manual          4             5     2020-05-03         0.8
```

Next, I need to get the average productivity based on the type and also date, the expected result:

```
type      date          avg
a       2020-05-06      0.613
b       2020-05-03      0.6
```

How should I write my query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```sql
select type, date, avg(qty/hour) as prod,
from table1
where id = 'manual'
group by type, date
```

I don't know how you generated your current intermediate results, but grouping by type and date must generate a result set of only 2 records, based on your sample input data.